# Do Ferengi ever blink their eyes?

Tags: star-trek, ferengi

I recently watched some Star Trek Deep Space Nine episodes and I noticed that the Ferengi never blink their eyes. Is it just the actors or do Ferengi as a race not need to blink their eyes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it was just the episode, and/or actor -- there's nothing in [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Portal%3aMain) about it, and if you look at [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG0ipvIoFZs), you see the Ferengi blink several seconds after the camera focuses on him.  (At 7 seconds.)  [This clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8yCRpYTBpQ&feature=related) has Nog blink at 1:11.

I'm sure there more, but I'm not up to the eyestrain of finding them :)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it was just [Quark](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quark) who's staring eyes confused me ;)

Comment: Seems that second video, you linked, is no longer available.